# Dispatch document click event on element in unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I need to unit test a service that handles browser events such as clicks inside/outside elements.

For this scenario I am trying to create a dummy element in the document from my unit test, issue a mouse click event on it, and verify that the returned target from the service is my element. However, I cannot get the click event on the element to trigger my listener in the service.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BrowserEventsService {
  private readonly document = inject(DOCUMENT);
  private readonly _documentClick$ = new Subject<EventTarget | null>();

  get documentClick$(): Observable<EventTarget | null> { return this._documentClick$.asObservable(); }

  constructor() {
    this.initDocumentClickListener();
  }

  private initDocumentClickListener(): void {
    fromEvent(this.document, 'click')
      .subscribe((event) => this._documentClick$.next(event.target));
  }
}
```

```
describe('BrowserEventsService', () => {
  let service: BrowserEventsService;
  let element: HTMLDivElement;

  function createElement(): void {
    element = document.createElement('div');
    element.setAttribute('id', 'test-div');
    const newContent = document.createTextNode('Hello World');
    element.appendChild(newContent);
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    createElement();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(BrowserEventsService);
  });

  it('should handle element click inside event', fakeAsync(() => {
    service.documentClick$.subscribe(target => {
      expect(target).toContain(element);
    });

    // I expected this to work, but it does not trigger the subscription in the service.
    element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));

    // I would have expected this to work as well, but .getElementById returns null.
    document.getElementById('test-id')?.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
    tick();
  }));
});
```

How can I correctly trigger my document click event in my service with a target of my test element?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking since the actual unit test document runs inside of an `iframe`, we probably need to append the element inside of the `iframe`.

You can see the picture that the test's DOM runs inside of the `root0` div.

We probably need to modify `createElement` like so:

It seems like you never attached it to the `DOM`. Maybe it doesn't have to be inside of the `root0` element.

```
function createElement(): void {
    element = document.createElement('div');
    element.setAttribute('id', 'test-div');
    const newContent = document.createTextNode('Hello World');
    element.appendChild(newContent);
    // add this element after the root0 div
    document.getElementById('root0').appendChild(element);
  }
```

You can also try just doing:

```
element.click();
```

instead of `dispatchEvent` to see if that works.

[image: DOM of a unit test]